# jQuery (attach, detach, reattach) event handlers issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

What I'm trying to do is to make a Datatable Editable. So the feature flow is this.

1. When clicking a cell, an input will be **CREATED**. So, whatever the cell has, it will be overwritten and moved to the value of the **created** input. (see an example of DataTables Editor, it works like that.)
2. Upon **blur** of the input. (Pressing *Enter* Key also triggers **blur**)

   a. If the value is unchanged, it will return to a normal cell (with its value unchanged of course)

   b. If the value was changed, it will stay as an input.

So, if I made an edit to a cell, it should stay as an input upon blur, but if I made an edit to that cell again, this time to input the original value, **UPON BLUR**, it should **NOW** shrink back into a cell.

But something weird is happening. This is the flow.

1. I click one cell, edit, make it lose focus. (so it will stay as an input)
2. I click another cell, edit, make it lose focus. (it will also stay as an input)
3. Now, when I click the cell that I've edited first, and retain it back to its original value. **UPON BLUR**, the cell which I've edited second, also returns back into a cell!

I'm suspecting a **scope/reference** issue here.

Feel free to see my working code in JSFiddle to understand the problem more.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UvjnT/2512/

For the JSFiddle, try to do these (in first row):

1. Click cell with Trident value.
2. Edit it, like add a letter. Like: aTrident
3. Now lose the focus, it will stay as an input.
4. Try clicking the cell with Internet value.
5. Edit it, for me it was: aInternet
6. Lose focus. It will remain as an input.
7. Now click the cell with aTrident value.
8. Edit it back to Trident.
9. See the bug happen.

To prove you that the feature is working and there's just a bug.

Try editing a cell, lose focus, edit it again to its original value, and watch it shrink back into a cell. :D

Help would be greaaaaaaat! :)

I'm running the following code on each ***on click*** of a **td** element inside the table.

```
el.html('<input class="table-edit form-control input-sm" type="text" value="' + val + '" />');
el.off('click');
input = el.children('input').first();
input.focus();
input.on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $(this).blur();
  }
});
input.on('blur', function(e) {
  newVal = $(this).val();
  if (val == newVal) {
    input.css('font-weight', 'normal');
    input.parent('td').css('outline', 'none');
    input.off('blur keyup');
    input.fadeOut('fast', function() {
      el.html(val);
      toInput(el, val);
    });
  } else {
    input.parent('td').css('outline', '1px solid #F79421');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the problem was here:

```
input.fadeOut('fast', function() {
      el.html(val);
      toInput(el, val); // <- this
    });
```

**Correction:** You forgot add `var` at `newVal = $(this).val();`.
This caused the variable `newVal` to be defined globally.

[Corrected JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UvjnT/2513/)

Comment: can you explain to me what happened? :(

Comment: found it ^.^ check the answer